# Show all used references when using compact numeric citation style

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, pandoc-citeproc

I'm rendering html from markdown using `bookdown`, and using a compact numeric citation style so that e.g., `1, 2, 3` is shown as `1-3`. I'd like references to be shown at the bottom of each page (`link-citations: yes`), but only the first and last reference in the range are shown (only refs 1 and 3 are shown, see screenshot below). Is there a way to have all cited references displayed on each page, with the caveat that only the first and last would be linked?

NB: all refs are correctly shown on the final bibliography.

To reproduce:

```
download.file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/7d824e2e0d4698cf8a6d5e784aa0df27a0f2888a/tests/biblio.bib', 'ex.bib')
download.file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/citation-style-language/styles/31187daa2c010df338c2bf9b7b30070c91b7af95/nature.csl', 'nature.csl')
```

and knit a markdown file with the following content:

```
---
title: A title
author: An author
bibliography: ex.bib
link-citations: yes
output:
  bookdown::gitbook:
    pandoc_args: [ "--csl", "nature.csl" ]
---

# Intro

baz [@item1; @item2; @пункт3]

# Refs
```

[image: resulting html]

---

#### Session info

```r
> sessioninfo::session_info()
─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
 os       macOS Mojave 10.14.3        
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_AU.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_AU.UTF-8                 
 tz       Australia/Melbourne         
 date     2020-03-29                  

─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 bookdown      0.17    2020-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 glue          1.3.2   2020-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 htmltools     0.4.0   2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 knitr         1.25    2019-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 packrat       0.5.0   2018-11-14 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 Rcpp          1.0.4   2020-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rlang         0.4.5   2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rmarkdown     1.16    2019-10-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rsconnect     0.8.15  2019-07-22 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rstudioapi    0.10    2019-03-19 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 xfun          0.10    2019-10-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 yaml          2.2.0   2018-07-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
```

```sh
❯ pandoc --version
pandoc 2.9.2.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.20, texmath 0.12.0.1, skylighting 0.8.3.2
...
Copyright (C) 2006-2020 John MacFarlane
Web:  https://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is no warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness
for a particular purpose.

❯ pandoc-citeproc --version
pandoc-citeproc 0.17
```

Comment: Related to https://community.rstudio.com/t/multi-paragraph-footnotes/47076/4 and https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/840?

Comment: I can't immediately see the connection, but maybe.

Comment: Note my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60909167/show-all-used-references-when-using-compact-numeric-citation-style#comment108027531_61019441). I plan to update this post describing the workaround in due course.

Answer (score 3):

My sense is that there are two elements you need to look at within the `nature.csl` file

**[Lines 104-131].**

The problem appears to be that your `bibliography` on line 112 is dependent on the `citation` definition on line 104. The term `collapse` interacts with your `bibliography` formating.

My recommendation is you take a look at the Citation Style Language web site and look over the reference styles to update your particular formating. Hoping this will help point you in the right direction.

1. [An Introduction to CSL](http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/1.0.1/primer.html)
2. [Citation Styles Example](https://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByName/) <- Super Useful
3. [IEEE Example](https://editor.citationstyles.org/styleInfo/?styleId=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotero.org%2Fstyles%2Fieee) <- Matches your described style
4. [Visual Editor to create a style of your choosing and download](https://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/)

my sense is you need to create a custom `cite-group-delimiter` definition in your `.csl` file rather than use a `collapse`. Can be tricky but feels doable.

5. http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#citation

---

```
<citation collapse="citation-number">
    <sort>
      <key variable="citation-number"/>
    </sort>
    <layout vertical-align="sup" delimiter=",">
      <text variable="citation-number"/>
    </layout>
  </citation>
  <bibliography et-al-min="6" et-al-use-first="1" second-field-align="flush" entry-spacing="0" line-spacing="2">
    <layout suffix=".">
      <text variable="citation-number" suffix="."/>
      <group delimiter=" ">
        <text macro="author" suffix="."/>
        <text macro="title" suffix="."/>
        <choose>
          <if type="chapter paper-conference" match="any">
            <text term="in"/>
          </if>
        </choose>
        <text macro="container-title"/>
        <text macro="editor"/>
        <text macro="volume"/>
        <text variable="page"/>
        <text macro="issuance"/>
        <text macro="access"/>
      </group>
    </layout>
  </bibliography>
```

**Citation**

The cs:citation element describes the formatting of citations, which consist of one or more references (“cites”) to bibliographic sources. Citations appear in the form of either in-text citations (in the author (e.g. “[Doe]”), author-date (“[Doe 1999]”), label (“[doe99]”) or number (“[1](http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/1.0.1/primer.html)”) format) or notes. The required cs:layout child element describes what, and how, bibliographic data should be included in the citations (see Layout). cs:layout may be preceded by a cs:sort element, which can be used to specify how cites within a citation should be sorted (see Sorting). The cs:citation element may carry attributes for Citation-specific Options and Inheritable Name Options. An example of a cs:citation element:

```
<citation>
  <sort>
    <key variable="citation-number"/>
  </sort>
  <layout>
    <text variable="citation-number"/>
  </layout>
</citation>
```

A note to CSL processor developers In note styles, a citation is often a sentence by itself. Therefore, the first character of a citation should preferably be uppercased when there is no preceding text in the note. In all other cases (e.g. when a citation is inserted into the middle of a pre-existing footnote), the citation should be printed as is.

**Bibliography**

The cs:bibliography element describes the formatting of bibliographies, which list one or more bibliographic sources. The required cs:layout child element describes how each bibliographic entry should be formatted. cs:layout may be preceded by a cs:sort element, which can be used to specify how references within the bibliography should be sorted (see Sorting). The cs:bibliography element may carry attributes for Bibliography-specific Options and Inheritable Name Options. An example of a cs:bibliography element:

```
<bibliography>
  <sort>
    <key macro="author"/>
  </sort>
  <layout>
    <group delimiter=". ">
      <text macro="author"/>
      <text variable="title"/>
    </group>
  </layout>
</bibliography>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Did you expect that your linked IEEE example would produce the desired ref list out of the box? I tested, thinking I could maybe modify that style to use superscript numbers, but it also omits reference 2 for my doc. (Note that the final reference list is accurate [for the nature style as well as your linked style] - all 3 references are shown. But the ref list for the current page is incomplete.)

Comment: @jbaums Always happy to help. I provided the IEEE as an example, with the knowledge that the current page reference list needs to be added to your .csl file as a modified definition. I was trying to find an example but I thought I should point you in the right direction in the immediate. It also hopefully will allow others to see how they might be able to provide a solution on top of what I shared.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - the links are certainly useful, much appreciated.

Comment: I'll noodle on it a bit more and update if I have the complete solution. Hopefully, others can also help out.

Comment: It turns out this is due to the way that bookdown treats cites when splitting the bib into chapters. I've hacked a solution [here](https://gist.github.com/johnbaums/40f973e2483150986fb53ca5e4200cbc), which can be applied after rendering the html with a non-compact numeric style (e.g. [this style](http://www.zotero.org/styles/nature) but with collapse="citation-number" deleted). Hopefully this will be supported by bookdown in future, or maybe @YihuiXie can suggest another workaround?